# How to given a fixed path to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

#### Code:

```
InputStream inputStream = System.in;
InputReader in = new InputReader(inputStream);
```

How could I modify this code to take a file from a fixed location?

#### Equivalent scanner example:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Max\\Desktop\\yes.txt"));
```

Comment: do you want to read a file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking for but if you don't want to hard code the path (which is generally not advisable) you could use a property or argument to `main(...)` which can be set in your run configuration in Eclipse.

Comment: yes!! i want to read a file

Comment: @Thomas can you explain how to that in eclipse

Comment: In Eclipse use `Run > Run Configurations...` and create a configuration for the type of application you want to run (most likely a "Java Application"). Then enter the path in the "Arguments" tab and finally run the configuration you just created (either via the "Run" button in the dialog or the run button in the menu bar which looks like a green "play" button).

Comment: @Thomas Program or VM Arguments ?

Comment: And what is wrong with FileReader?

Comment: You might want to read the documentation on that. Basically it depends on how you want to get the value. VM arguments would be properties (i.e. what you'd pass with `-Dxxx`) while program arguments would be what you pass to `main()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Could you please mark as accepted the answer that was the most helpful? It shows other users that your problem was solved, and which answer to check out first.

Answer (score 2):

if you only want the whole text in one string than you can use the `FileInputStream`

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("foo.txt");
try {
    String everything = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
} finally {
    inputStream.close();
}
```

if you want to read the file line bye line use the `BufferdReader` in Connection with `StringBuilder`

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

while (line != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    line = br.readLine();
}
String everything = sb.toString();

}finally {
    br.close();
}
```

**Note:**

The examples are taken from @Knubo and the whole answer and further Information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

To read file using Scanner class.

Try this.

```
Scanner input=null;
try{
    input=new Scanner(new File("your_file_path\yes.txt"));
} catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}

while(input.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(input.next());
}

input.close();
```